# Make a button that evaluates a function over and over

Tags: evaluation, dynamic

I would like to have a command "RedoButton" which would make a button (or whatever control is suitable) that when clicked would print the value of a certain function over and over *in the same place*.  So for example `RedoButton["do it", RandomInteger[{1, 10}]` would produce a button that, when clicked, would produce a random integer of the sort required, clicking it again would produce a possibly different random integer where the old one was, and so on.  I have tried `Toggle`, `Button`, and numerous other commands but can't make any of them work correctly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this

```
SetAttributes[redoButton, HoldRest]
redoButton[str_, fun_] := DynamicModule[{result = Null}, 
   Column[{Button[str, result = fun], Dynamic[result]}]]

redoButton["press", RandomInteger[20]]
```

Comment: That works -- thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the button itself to show the current value, this may help:

```
Button[Dynamic[x], x = RandomInteger[{1, 20}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then use `x` or `Dynamic[x]` etc. for further computation/display.