# Slow Dynamic Button Does Not Print

Tags: dynamic, evaluation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do buttons with ChoiceDialog freeze the front end?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/why-do-buttons-with-choicedialog-freeze-the-front-end)
>   [Why is SystemDialogInput failing to return a save file path?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7091/why-is-systemdialoginput-failing-to-return-a-save-file-path)
>   [Evaluation inside Button stops after some seconds](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/evaluation-inside-button-stops-after-some-seconds)

I am trying to use the code from:

[Make a button that evaluates a function over and over](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4967/make-a-button-that-evaluates-a-function-over-and-over)

to make a button evaluate some code and plot the results, but when the code takes more than a few seconds it does not plot the results.

Here is a simple example that illustrates the problem I am having

For short time periods it works fine:

```
    func := (Pause[1]; Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}]);
    DynamicModule[{result = Null},  Column[{Button["Press", result = func], Dynamic[result]}]]
```

But if I change the pause to be 10 seconds it doesn't show the plot

```
    func := (Pause[10]; Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}]);
    DynamicModule[{result = Null},  Column[{Button["Press", result = func], Dynamic[result]}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
func := (Pause[10]; Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}]);
DynamicModule[{result = Null}, 
Column[{Button["Press", result = func, Method -> "Queued"], 
Dynamic[result]}]]
```

From MMA documentation:

> By default, button functions are evaluated on a preemptive link, which times out after 5 seconds:

Use `Method->"Queued"` to evaluate button functions, which never times out.

Comment: Perfect thank you!