# Can't see dynamic updating when my function is evaluated inside Dynamic

Tags: dynamic

I defined a function, `solve`, with a free variable n, which changes while `solve` is running. Therefore, evaluating

```
Dynamic[n]

solve[];
```

allows me to see the changes. But when I put `solve` into any sort of interface element like a button, I dont see n changing. Even if I evaluate

```
Dynamic[n]

bn = 0;
Dynamic[If[bn === 1, {bn = 0, solve[x]}]]

bn = 1;
```

I only see n change when the evaluation of `solve` is complete. What do I need to do to be able to observe changes to n as they happen?

#### Edit

With this, I see n change as evaluation progresses:

```
n = 0; solve[] :=  Do[n += 1, {1000000}]; Dynamic[n]; solve[]
```

With this, I only see n change at the end when it reaches 1000000:

```
bn = 0; Dynamic[If[bn === 1, {solve[], bn = 0}]]; bn = 1;
```

Comment: Please post the code defining `solve`. Without this we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: n = 0;

solve[] := Do[n += 1, {1000000}];

Dynamic[n]

solve[] <- This makes n changes along progress 

Dynamic[If[bn === 1, {solve[], bn = 0}]];

bn = 1; <- here i see n only change at end to 2000000

Comment: Please do not put requested example code in a comment. Add it to your original question as an edit. This time, because you are new to _Mathematica_.SE, I did it for you to show how it's done.

Comment: We've had quite a few similar questions. For example, see [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10224/slow-dynamic-button-does-not-print)

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not show some code, I am here guessing what your problem can be from your mention of the use of a `Button`.

First, a direct example that works as is:

```
n = 0;
Dynamic[n]
solve[] := Module[{i},
  Do[n++; Pause[.21], {i, 10}]
  ]
```

Now, if you put this in a `Button` as is, you will only see the final result:

```
n = 0;
Dynamic[n]
Button["click me", Do[n++; Pause[.2], {i, 10}]]
```

However, to see `n` changes after you click the button, you need to set the `Method` option:

```
n = 0;
Dynamic[n]
Button["click me", Do[n++; Pause[.2], {i, 10}], Method -> "Queued"]
```

Now you will see `n` changes.

Comment: Thank you , Method -> "Queued" worked